# Password encryption for variable in swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, password-protection

I have a variable `var password = ""`. The application has registration page where the password is in secure input entry form.

Then I have to pass the password from one controller to another, so I am assigning it to the password variable, to compelete the registration process.

```
password = passwordtextField.text

Class A{
var password = ""
@IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField:UITextField!

//save function
password = passwordtextField.text

//pass the data to next class to complete registration
let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "BControllerid") as! BViewController
  vc.passwordB = password

}

Class BViewController{
var passwordB = ""

//viewDiLoad
request.body = ["password" : passwordB]
//call the request
}
```

My question is: 
1.Should I encrypt the password being assigned to the variable? If so, how to do it? and Do i have to decrypt it again before making API call?
2. Is it safe to assign the password and pass on to next class as implemented?

Comment: why do you need to encrypt the password in the client? Can you do it in the backend? I am assuming you are using `https` with your API calls.

Comment: I don't think what you are trying to do makes it safer in any kinds of way.

Comment: @BrunoPaulino Yeah. That was my question was as I also believe it is not required to do so. https is being used. Thank you

Comment: @BlackPearl12 so you can pass the plain password and encrypt it safely in the backend. make sure to use a salt to make it even more secure.

Comment: Thanks @BrunoPaulino . Backend is already secure. The whole question was because of sonarqube. Should mark it as false positive.

Comment: You don't need to encrypt the password as you pass it around in your app, but best practice is to hash the password on the device and send the hash to your backend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For question 1:**

No, you don't need to encrypt it, because it is being used within the app. No one can have access to read that variable outside of your code.

Well, you can do the same mechanism while sending the password to API, because if your network is not secure or someone tries to interrupt in middle of your API call and app, then he can get these information. so, better encrypt the password while sending to API and store it in encrypted form to database.

**For question 2:**

Yes, that is safe to do the same. As said, it is always within your project so, no one will going to readout the variables and the assigned values except the responsible class.

Hope it clears.

Answer (score 2):

Here are the answers of your questions:

1. 1.Should I encrypt the password being assigned to the variable? If so, how to do it? and Do i have to decrypt it again before making
   API call?

   - No need to encrypt password when your are just passing between classes or controllers. You should not decrypt your password when you send it to server if you decrypt there is no meaning of encryption. If you are not using HTTPS then it is highly recommend to encrypt your password.
2. Is it safe to assign the password and pass on to next class as implemented?

   - Yes it is safe as it is within is your project only.

Comment: @BlackPearl12 No worries. You should accept best answer. :)

Comment: Had to do First answer accept. Both are same adn serve my purpose. (y)